# NSInternalInconsistencyException when using insertSections instead of reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
var data = [InboxPosts]()

func setup() {

  AF.request("https://example.com", method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
    .validate().responseData { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .success(let data):

        //get data from service

        let rel = InboxPosts(userid: id, name: name)

        if !self.data.contains(rel) {
          self.data.append(rel)
        }

        let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: self.data.count - 1)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

      }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  setup()
}
```

I add data to array and call InsertSections

```
func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func numberOfSections(in _: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

If I use reloadData() it works good but when I use insertSections I get

```
Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (16) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (1 inserted, 0 deleted)
```

When the new data is available I don't want to use reloadData and add cells using insertSections but how can I fix this issue?

Comment: The problem is in code not shown. Where did the new item come from? Is it the result of some Asynchronous operation such as a network fetch? It looks like you have a race condition.  According to the error your tableview had no sections, you are trying to insert 1 new section, but `numberOfSections` is returning 16

Comment: @Paulw11 just an API request with Alamofire and appending the result to data array then trying to insert to tableview

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code in the context of processing your network response.

Comment: @Paulw11 edited and added the code to show structure

Comment: Your code doesn't look correct. You only append if the object doesn't already exist in the array, but you always insert a section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using this code

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()

self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, self.data.count)) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)

self.tableView.endUpdates()
```